# iOS Segue alternative for OSX

Tags: ios, macos, segue, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I am new to OSX. My Mac Os x app have 3 to 4 screen. What I want to do is click on next button it will transfer from first Screen to Second Screen. 
Like iOS on click of button We can set segue and It will redirect to given ViewController. 
How to achieve same thing in Mac os x App?

Comment: I don’t know AppKit, but Apple added storyboard support in OS X Yosemite. Maybe something in there can do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboards were added to the mac in 10.10. It works the same as under ios6+.

Also programmatically it is equivalent... well except `UISegue` is now called `NSStoryboardSegue` ;)

---

before 10.10 you'd have to do all the navigational stuff yourself using addSubview & removeSubview to switch out the views of a window (same as in ios1-4 when you didn't use a navigationController to abstract that away)